# Previous owner can still see private records despite criteria based sharing rule

Tags: sharing, sharing-rule, criteria-based-sharing

I have an issue where my criteria based sharing rule doesn't seem to be affecting record visibility. I've set OWD to the object as Private and users do not have View All permissions.

I then created a sharing rule that shares all records of the object to all internal users when a Field *does not equal* a particular value. When that value is selected I'm changing the owner of the record to the user's manager yet the previous owner is still able to see the original record.

Am I missing something? What I'm trying to achieve here is a sort of escalation mechanism where the user's manager now owns the record and the user can no longer see it.

Comment: Step 1 -- add the Sharing button to your layout, then click it - it will show the reason why the record is visible to that user.

Comment: Can you check does the previous owner belongs to internal user? if so then he/she will have access using sharing rule.

Comment: I realized the manager was a part of a case queue and that allowed the previous owner to still be able to see the record since it was related to a case record.

Once I removed the manager from the case queue the Account record is hidden from the previous owner now. However, I have a Flow that's configured to run after the record saves that changes the Account record owner based on a Field. 

When that Flow runs the user gets an error that says "the requested resource does not exist" when trying to save because the owner change. The error is misleading because the record does actually save.